# Setting delegate of a UITableViewController using Storyboards

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, delegates, storyboard

I am trying to set the delegate of a `UITableViewController` using Storyboards. The problem I am having is that the `UITableViewController`'s delegate I want to set, is not simply the initial view controller destination. Therefore I decided I would use this method once launching the app:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
AddListTermsViewController *addListTerms = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AddListTerms"];
addListTerms.delegate = self;
}
```

I then set the Storyboard ID of the `UITableViewController` like so:

[image]

But when I launch the `UITableViewController` and log the delegate, I receive null.
Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

When I log the output in the initial view controller like so, I get a positive result:

```
AddListTermsViewController *addListTerms = (AddListTermsViewController*)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AddListTerms"];
addListTerms.delegate = self;
NSLog(@"%@", addListTerms.delegate);
```

But when I log the output on the `UITableViewController` I again receive **null**

Comment: I think your's addListTerms is also null.

Answer (score 0):

i guess you need to typecast storyboadcontroller to AddListTermsViewController

try this

```
  AddListTermsViewController *addListTerms = (AddListTermsViewController*)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AddListTerms"];
```

Comment: @AlexanderMacLeod : What's your tableview name in AddListTermsViewController ?

Comment: It does not have a name as it as UITableViewController.

Comment: you missed to set the dataSource addListTerms.dataSource = self;

Comment: I do not have a dateSource. I created a delegate like so, so that I could transfer data between the two classes: @property (nonatomic, weak) id <AddListTermsViewControllerDelegate> delegate;